# How to tell Flash CS6 to embed Preloader classes on frame 1 and the rest on frame 2?

Tags: actionscript-3, embed, assets, preloader, flash-cs6

I have a project with a preloader on Frame 1, and all my assets on Frame 2 (and mostly controlled by a Main class that instantiates all the Bitmaps / Animations at that frame via code).

But even if I set all my **Bitmap** and **MovieClip** assets to NOT export on frame 1, it exports all my Classes on frame one.

So I've changed it within the **Advanced ActionScript 3.0** Publish settings to export classes on Frame 2.

[image: Flash CS6 delima, how to export a Preloader on frame 1 (and it's dependencies), but the rest on frame 2?]

BUT, now EVERYTHING seems to be exported on Frame 2 (Classes and Assets). Nothing shows up on Frame 1 when I run the SWF (it shows empty white areas where the assets would normally appear).

How can I get just my **Preloader Assets & Class** on Frame #1, and just the **remaining Assets & Classes** on Frame #2?

Comment: why not to simply put your `Preloader` on the frame 1 ???

Comment: The Preloader is also written as a Class, and I don't want to simply copy & paste its code to the timeline. I want to avoid placing code to the timeline as much as possible.

Comment: You working with Flash IDE only? how many frames you have on the main timeline?

Comment: I've got it working in the end, but it's a struggle every time I try it the first time around. The frames were expanded a few frames to be able to read out the whole frame-labels (frame 1: "preloader", frame 9: "main"). What ended up working in the end was setting my Preloader class as the document class, a `stop()` action on frame 1,  a few TextFields on frame "main" with the imported Fonts I need to embed, and an empty MovieClip that has a class-linkage to my Assets.as class (which contains all the [Embed] tags of external resources). It may sound like an odd approach, but it works! :)

Comment: Oh! And I also put the "Export classes in frame" to 9 (the "main" frame label).

Comment: glad you fixed it. but i suggest you to start develop your code with FlashDevelop , its free , comfort and increasing the speed of writing of course. after you start with it you'll never be able to go back to write code with Flash IDE. Flash is only for creating graphics assets , animations and stuff but not for coding! in FlashDevelop you can embed first only your preloaders animation , and after that to "lazy" load all other graphics .

Comment: Haha but the problem is I DO use FlashDevelop on a daily basis, but this project was for a company that couldn't use FlashDevelop (or was afraid of change... more likely). I even had my project all ready, with a preloader, and showing significant filesize reduction on frame 1 and even frame 2. But! have to please the clients with an FLA they can use.